# Target :last-child with mixed class siblings?

Tags: css

How do I target the last child of a class when there are siblings with another class after it? It would be nice to have a `:last-sibling` and `:last-sibling-of-type`.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/nge20o5L/)

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div> /* How do I target this if its nth position is unknowable? */
  <div class="grid-orphan"></div>
  <div class="grid-orphan"></div>
  <div class="grid-orphan"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class (there is the last-element variant but not able to find it ..)

Comment: CSS is too short for this task. Add the second class (when you generated this markup) or use JavaScript.

Comment: If the only variant here is the number of grid-item, you can still use nth-last-child(4), but you might consider using a class modifier instead

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the last `.grid-item` element out of the document, regardless of what it's inside, then you can't do that in CSS. In CSS, you can only select the first, last, or nth element at one particular level of the hierarchy, you can't select the last element of some type regardless of what it's nested in.

Here is one way to get the last div inside of `.grid`

`.grid div:last-of-type`

Here's another way to get the last child of some outer div:

`div :last-child`

**BUT The thing you probably need is some js:**

You could do this the jquery approach (like below), or just do  `getElementsByClassName`and then set the last element in the list in the same manner.

```js
function getlastchild() {

  var items = $(".grid-item");

  items.last().css("background-color", "red");
  //OR even as one-liner: $(".grid-item").last().css("background-color", "red");

}
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 200px;
}

.grid div:last-of-type {
  color: white;
}

div:last-child {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-orphan">5</div>
  <div class="grid-orphan">6</div>
  <div class="grid-orphan">7</div>
</div>

<button onclick="getlastchild()">Press me to get last grid-item</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 4 possibilities here:

**Case 1:**

You already know the number of `grid-orphan` items, so you can use `nth-last-child`.

```
.grid-item:nth-last-child(4) {
    background: blue;
}
```

**Case 2:**

You are an adventurer and this is not for production: use the newest version of `nth-child` and `nth-last-child`:

```
.grid-item:nth-last-child(1 of .grid-item) {
    background: blue;
}
```

However, it only works on Safari for now ([12.99%](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-nth-child-of)).

[See specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#the-nth-child-pseudo)

**Case 3:**

Use JavaScript.

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item')
const selectedItem = [].slice.call(items).pop();

selectedItem.style.background = 'blue';
```

**Case 4:**

Just add an extra class.

```
<div class="grid-item grid-item--special"></div>
```

```
.grid-item.grid-item--special {
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: This is great. For case 1 I think you meant just "last-child" as nth-last-child is Case 2.

Comment: I meant `nth-last-child` for both cases. Just note that the first case is in the context of all children (*grid-item* and *grid-orphan*) while the second one is in the context of *grid-item* only.

Answer (score -1):

You can use either :nth-last-child or [:nth-last-of-type](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-of-type/) if you are able to put all your `.grid-orphan` elements inside another `div`.

HTML

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-orphans">
    <div class="grid-orphan"></div>
    <div class="grid-orphan"></div>
    <div class="grid-orphan"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;

  .grid-item {
    background: gray;
    border: 1px solid white;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100px;
    width: calc(25% - 20px);
    min-width: 360px;
    flex-grow: 2;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    cursor: pointer;

    &:nth-last-child(2) {
      background: navy;
    }
  }

  .grid-orphan {
    height: 0;
    border: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: calc(25% - 20px);
    min-width: 360px;
    flex-grow: 2;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

Jsfiddle available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/siavasfiroozbakht/uwgaxfe4/).

Otherwise, a CSS-only approach would be limited to [only Apple's browsers](https://www.caniuse.com/#feat=css-nth-child-of), that is Safari desktop and on iOS, since they are the only ones that implement the selector list argument, which allows you to narrow down the elements by a class selector. For seeing this just change `&:nth-last-child(2)` with `&:nth-last-child(1 of .grid-item)`

Comment: I can change the orphans to spans and use last-of-type, but not if all elements are the same type (divs).

Comment: This is indeed true @KirkRoss. Have updated my answer with an alternative.

Answer (score -1):

All those answers are great. Thank you. I ended up just making the orphans `<span>'s` and then `.grid-item:last-child` worked fine. I knew I could do that but was wondering if it could be done (easily) when the orphans were the same element type as the grid items.

Comment: You mean `.grid-item:last-of-type`?

Comment: Quite likely he did `last-of-type` @QuentinVeron. OP, as you are able to change your markup I'd rather do it with my approach (nesting `.grid-orphan`s into another div and using `.nth-last-child(2)`. [`span`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) should be used only for phrasing content.